# NGINX 403 Forbidden - CentOS - Certbot

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate, webserver, certbot

I followed this tutorial: https://linuxize.com/post/secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7/

My server is running CentOS7 of course with NGINX. After following the entire thing and debugging what is going on, I am stuck.

I am now getting a 403 Forbidden when visiting the subdomain we installed the Cert on. Below are my nginx.conf file and my sites conf file from /etc/nginx/conf.d

I can't access my site because we force redirection to HTTPS of course and getting the 403. /var/www/pterodactyl/public is the root of my website.

NGINX.CONF:
//

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;



events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root        /var/www/pterodactyl/public;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /var/www/pterodactyl/public;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

//

and then my sites config

//

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.panel.example.com panel.example.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.panel.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchainchain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://panel.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name panel.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;



    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/pterodactyl.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

So I do have a letsencrypt.conf file where I have location laid out like this:
//

```
location ~ /\.well-known {
  allow all;
  root /var/lib/letsencrypt/;
  default_type "text/plain";
  try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Weird though when I run the nginx -t right now I get this:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.panel.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "panel.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

My letsencrypt file is above and ssl.conf file match that tutorial. Of course example.com is replaced with my domain.

AFTER RUNNING NGINX -T

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root        /var/www/pterodactyl/public;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /var/www/pterodactyl/public;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}


# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-mail.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-stream.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    d                                                                                                                                                             ocx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          x                                                                                                                                                             lsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  p                                                                                                                                                             ptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/pterodactyl.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name panel.example.com;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    root /var/www/pterodactyl/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # the fastcgi_pass path needs to be changed accordingly when using CentO                                                                                                                                                             S
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100                                                                                                                                                             M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.panel.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchain.pem                                                                                                                                                             ;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://panel.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name panel.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;



    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/pterodactyl.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100                                                                                                                                                             M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf:
location ~ /\.well-known {
  allow all;
  root /var/lib/letsencrypt/;
  default_type "text/plain";
  try_files $uri =404;
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf:
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECD                                                                                                                                                             SA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:E                                                                                                                                                             CDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:E                                                                                                                                                             CDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RS                                                                                                                                                             A-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES25                                                                                                                                                             6-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES2                                                                                                                                                             56-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH                                                                                                                                                             -RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA25                                                                                                                                                             6:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 30s;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; prelo                                                                                                                                                             ad";
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/pterodactyl_old.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.panel.example.com panel.example.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.panel.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://panel.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name panel.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;



    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/pterodactyl.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100                                                                                                                                                             M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the actual configuration that Nginx is reading. I cannot see a conflicting server name, so maybe Nginx is reading more than one file from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` (a backup file perhaps). Also, your `server` block for `panel.example.com` does not have a `root` statement. Where are the files for this site located?

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you, so after running nginx -T I got what I pasted at the end of the original post.

Only weird thing I can see is for TLS settings for http, it shows ssl cert as something that doesn't exist, should I change this? Do you see anything else? Thanks!

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";

Comment: @RichardSmith Checked Pterodactyl.app. error log and I see this:

2020/01/25 11:45:25 [error] 9885#0: *775 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: IP_here, server: panel.gameeo.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "panel.example.com"

My server directory should be /var/www/pterodactyl/public

Comment: You have two configuration files `pterodactyl.conf` and `pterodactyl_old.conf` which are both being read by Nginx which is causing the duplicate names. And you are missing a `root /var/www/pterodactyl/public;` statement in some of your `server` blocks, which is why Nginx is attempting to find files at `/usr/share/nginx/html/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Fixed that, I started fresh with new config files etc. I now think everything is setup properly but now I am getting a ```502 bad gateway```, I installed a new cert and all.

In Pterodactyl error log I get this now: ```2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)``` 
' while connecting to upstream,

Any ideas?

Comment: @RichardSmith Seems when I check my file structure I have /run/php-fpm/pterodactyl.soc for the panel I am using. Do I need to change it to this?